# sql - Query syntax issue with adding sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I cannot seem to execute this query without any syntax errors, I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "TBL1.Avg_CycleTime" could not be bound.

QUERY:

```
SELECT (AVG(TBL1.Avg_CycleTime + TBL4.Avg_GRM_CycleTime)) AS Overall_Renewals_CycleTime
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT AVG(1.00 * Avg_DayDiff) AS Avg_CycleTime
        FROM (
            SELECT AVG(1.00 * DATEDIFF(DAY, yy, xx)) AS Avg_DayDiff
            FROM Database1.dbo.tbl_1
            WHERE month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
                AND year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
            ) t1
        WHERE Avg_DayDiff > 0
        ) TBL1
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT AVG(1.00 * Avg_DayDiff) AS Avg_GRM_CycleTime
            FROM (
                SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, uu) AS Avg_DayDiff
                FROM Database1.dbo.tbl_1
                WHERE month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
                    AND year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month, - 1, current_timestamp))
                    AND ApprovalRequiredFrom = 'GRM'
                ) t2
            WHERE Avg_DayDiff > 0
            ) TBL2
        ) TBL3
    ) TBL4
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I would like to get the AVERAGE between (Avg_cycletime & avg_grm_cycletime)

cheers,

Comment: I suggest baby steps.  Build this one step at a time and fix any errors you encounter on the way.  Start at the innermost subquery and work your way outwards.

Comment: change TBL1.Avg_CycleTime to  Avg_CycleTime

Comment: The problem in this holy-hell-nested-nightmare is your top line `AVG(TBL1.Avg_CycleTime + TBL4.Avg_GRM_CycleTime)` There is no Tbl1 in context here. Only a `TBL4`.

Comment: since there is only 1 Avg_CycleTime in the query you don't need to qualify the field with 'Tbl1 .' at all

Answer (score 2):

-- in your select you are selecting values from TBL1 (that are in sub query that do not exist in your FROM.  Change that to TBL4

```
select (AVG(TBL1.Avg_CycleTime + TBL4.Avg_GRM_CycleTime)) as Overall_Renewals_CycleTime
from ()
  )TBL4
```

Also I would not use so many nested selects, or at least not Select * (Selecting * is never good idea).